# Accessing C$ over LAN on Win2008R2 - cannot by hostname but can by IP and FQDN

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

Having an issue with one of our Win2k8 R2 file servers. Trying to access C$ or the Admin share is giving us an error (see error details that the bottom), however we are able to connect using the server's IP and FQDN.

- can access `\\172.16.x.x\c$` with domain cred
- can access `\\server.domain.local\c$` with domain creds
- cannot access `\\servername\c$` with same domain creds

Server pings fine with Hostname, IP, FQDN, the Primary DNS suffix is also correct.

DNS, PTR and Wins records are all correct for the Server

I have checked that I am not trying to connect with cached credentials in the Windows vault, the server is also appending primary and connection specific DNS suffixes to the hostname.

Any ideas what might be causing this issue?

Error Details:

> c$ is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this
>   network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out
>   if you have access permissions

### update

@ChrisMcKeown comment was the solution I was looking for.

Seems that because I was trying to access C$ on a file server that I had already mapped shared to my computer using just its Hostname, e.g. z: \serverhostname\companyshare

It would not allow me to connect when explicitly supplying domain credentials to the C$ and Admin$ shares.

Not 100% sure why this is the case, but seems that it sees the IP, Hostname and FQDN as separate entities, if anyone can clear that part up it would be great.

Comment: Are you explicitly supplying credentials when you connect? Check `NET USE` and see if you already have a connection to that server using just its hostname - if you do then it won't allow you to create another connection to the same server with different credentials - although as you have found, you can use the FQDN or the IP instead to create a new connection.

Comment: yes it strange,  best bet is that its not using the same security scheme or it can't negotiate the correct security scheme when you select \\servername\c$ not sure how. I'd put netmon on and watch things.

Comment: the error message is incorrect I think for trying to connnect to the same share with different creds.

Comment: @ChrisMcKeown - I am explicitly supplying different credentials when trying to connect to this share (my second user account with additional privileges)

As this server is one of our main file server, there are mapped connections to hosted shares on the box(not c$ or admin$) accessing the server using just the hostname e.g.
z:  \\servername\usershares 

So because of these mapped shares, I cannot connect to \\serverhostname\c$ and supply my admin creds because of the hostanme is already used with the mapped shares?

Comment: Removed all connections to hosted shares on the server.  This allowed me to connect to c$

Comment: @Idgoo correct, you cannot connect to multiple shares on the same machine using different credentials. An way around this (which you found) is that you can use the FQDN and the IP address which will effectively allow you to have three different sets of credentials connecting to the same server. I'll add this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you already have a connection to `\\serverhostname` using a different set of credentials from the ones you are trying to use to connect to `C$`.

You cannot connect to multiple shares on the same machine using different credentials. A way around this (which you found) is that you can use the FQDN and the IP address which will effectively allow you to have three different sets of credentials connecting to the same server.